# Moving with rotating in 3D world in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create a first person system in my game which consist of a big cube with grass texture , so the problem happens when I move and try to rotate the camera the world rotate and I'm not on the main axis this is code

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3();

private void movement() {
    block.transform.getTranslation(position);
    position.x = x;
    position.z = z;
    position.y = y;
    block.transform.setTranslation(position);

}

private void rotate() {
    //camera.rotate(Vector3.Y,angleX);
    //block.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y,360.0f - angleY);
    block.transform.setFromEulerAngles(angleY, 0, 0).trn(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    carinstance.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y,angleY);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.5f, .7f, .9f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL30.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    movement();
    rotate();

    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    modelBatch.render(modelInstance,environment);

    modelBatch.end();
    camera.update();

}
```

I know that we must rotate the world and move it not the camera and I did this in openGL so I used

```
glrotatef(anglex,0,1,0);
```

To rotate the all world but in libgdx I can't find a way to do this .

I just want a way to move and rotate camera in libgdx.